# Extract the year from an array of dates

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have an array with a lot of dates, an example below.

```
array(4) { ["1939-05-19"]=> int(2) ["1939-02-17"]=> int(1) ["1939-04-21"]=> int(1) ["1941-09-18"]=> int(1) }
```

What I want to be able to do in PHP is change this array so that all I have is the year and not the day or month, is that possible?  So it would look something like this:

```
array(2) { ["1939"]=> int(3) ["1941"]=> int(1) }
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to far?

Comment: That is kind of my issue, I am not sure what to try.  This for a new timeline for my website.  I want to get the year from each event and then turn the list of years into a link that will produce only the items for that particular year.  That I can do once I can get the array down to a list of years only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the keys to get the string up to the first `-` and combine that with the existing values:

```
$result = array_combine(array_map(function($v) {
                                      return strstr($v, '-', true);
                                  },
                                  array_keys($array)), $array);
```

You can do the same with `strtotime` and `date` in the function, but you seem to be having issues with that:

```
$result = array_combine(array_map(function($v) {
                                      return date('Y', strtotime($v));
                                  },
                                  array_keys($array)), $array);
```

But now I see you're trying to sum the values for the years, so do the same and use that as the key and add each new one:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $year = strstr($key, '-', true);
    if(isset($result[$year])) {
        $result[$year] += $value;
    } else {
        $result[$year] = $value;
    }
}
```

Or do that but use `strtotime`:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($key));
    if(isset($result[$year])) {
        $result[$year] += $value;
    } else {
        $result[$year] = $value;
    }
}
```